# Todos os programadores de código de máquina que reclamaram sobre Assembly mudaram de idéia sobre o Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arquitetura-computadores

Segundo Richard Hamming no livro *A Arte de fazer ciência e engenharia*, página 26, uma das principais reclamações dos programadores de código de máquina da 1° geração que não aceitaram o Assembly foi que você nunca sabe onde o Assembly coloca as coisas.

O original da afirmação que falei acima diz (grifos meus):

> Finally, a more complete, and more useful, Symbolic Assembly Program(SAP) was devised-after more years than you are apt to believe during which most programmers continued their heroic absolute binary programming. At the time SAP first appeared I would guess about 1% of the older programmers were interested in it-using SAP was "sissy stuff", and a real programmers would not stoop to wasting machine capacity to do the assembly.Yes! Programmers wanted no part of it, though when pressed they had to admit their old methods used more machine time in locating and fixing up errors than the SAP program ever used. **One of the main complaints was when using a symbolic system you do not know where anything was in storage** - though in the early days we supplied a mapping of symbolic to actual storage, and believe it or not they later lovingly pored over such sheets rather than realize they did not need to know that information if they stuck to operating within the system -no! When correcting errors they preferred to do it in absolute binary.

referência: http://worrydream.com/refs/Hamming-TheArtOfDoingScienceAndEngineering.pdf

Eu não entendi porque 1% dos programadores que codificavam em código de máquina que não aceitaram o Assembly depois aceitaram o Assembly.

Se não for pedir demais, por favor, alguém traduza o texto inglês de Richard Hamming que eu citei acima.

Eu fiz a pergunta baseada na seguinte parte: One of the main complaints was when using a symbolic system you do not know where anything was in storage.

Traduzindo fica assim: 'Uma das principais reclamações foi que quem utiliza um sistema simbólico não sabe onde tudo é colocado na memória.'

Eu não entendi porque programadores de código de máquina reclamaram sobre o Assembly e também não entendi porque 1% dos programadores de código de máquina que acreditaram que o Assembly era uma heresia mudaram de idéia sobre o Assembly.

Todos os programadores de código de máquina que reclamaram sobre Assembly mudaram de idéia sobre o Assembly?

Comment: A pergunta parece boa mas talvez precise de mais contexto. Já tem gente achando que ela não está clara. Não sei se é o caso, talvez porque não está claro onde você quer chegar com isto. Mas acho que não deixar é um termo exagerado, acho que só dificulta um pouco.

Comment: **- La pergunta?**

Comment: bigown, eu fiz a pergunta baseada na seguinte parte: One of the main complaints was when using a symbolic system you do not know where anything was in storage.  Traduzindo fica assim:Uma das principais reclamações foi ao utilizar um sistema simbólico que você não sabe onde tudo estava em armazenamento.

Comment: Eu não vou votar para fechar porque pode ser que seja porque eu não entendo do assunto mas não consegui entender do que se trata. Parece falar em *assembly* como se fosse uma coisa única que normalmente não é. Então talvez seja algo que eu nem tenho ideia do que seja. E mesmo assim acho que a premissa da pergunta está errada, mas pode ser falha minha.

Comment: Você quer saber o que exatamente? tenta simplificar a pergunta, está tentando resolver algum problema particular analisando a estrutura de algum fonte ou está discutindo um problema de design/arquitetura de uma cadeira que você está pagando? Está vago ...

Comment: Eu acho que o problema ao formular a pergunta é que ele traduziu mal o que está escrito, ou talvez o "português" dele seja diferente do da maioria aqui... O que eu entendi é que ele não entendeu o motivo de haverem programadores de máquina tem uma reclamação sobre assembly, mas não é claro o motivo e ele quer saber como funciona e o por que desta "fama" - acho que deixei mais confuso que a pergunta

Answer (score 3):

A graça de programar em assembly ao invés de diretamente em linguagem de máquina é justamente que você pode dar nomes às coisas ao invés de se referir a tudo diretamente pelo endereço da memória. Por exemplo, em assembly você pode fazer um goto para um label ao invés de diretamente para um endereço numérico. Se você adicionar uma linha no programa o endereço do label é recalculado de forma automática durante a compilação e irá apontar pro lugar certo.

Se você realmente quiser, você pode escrever todos os endereços de memória diretamente e escolher quais variáveis vão em qual lugar mas aí você acaba não aproveitando uma das principais funcionalidades do assembler...

Comment: e rão? É uma gralha?